# Python web framework php alike

Tags: php, python

Yes, I'm in doubt if that's a duplicate, I've searched a while but nothing exactly like this one.

I'm a hobbyist programmer, I know C++ and python well, but I'm a completely noob when it comes to web-development, it sounds more natural to me to learn PHP without frameworks, but then comes the question, **is there any python module or framework that allow me to develop websites like in php-without-frameworks?**, because i really prefer python over php, and also i pretend to move to Django after i learned the basics in the **hard way**.

I also want to code javascript and css by my own, i just want this module/framework that concatenates the native approach for web of php, but in python language 'cause i love it.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "php-without-frameworks"? Do you mean where all the logic is splurged into the middle of the templates? That's terrible style (even in PHP) and should be avoided for anything other then the most very quick and dirty scripts.

Comment: If you're confident with python, why do you want to learn php as an additional language? I'm just asking, not saying you shouldn't, just if you share more of your motivation it might become more clear what you're looking for in the PHP world.

Comment: if you don't need/want a framework why are you looking for a framework? :)

Comment: @Quentin, I just wanna learn the hard way, but i wanna use python, and i want the most "standard" way of doing this in python, without frameworks, like in php ( without frameworks )

Comment: @hakre, that's the point, php sounds more didatic to new web-developers, since it is more easy to simple start using for webdev.

Comment: @yi_H, because python isn't towards web so much like nude php is.

Comment: @Alfred, i'm going to keep using it, you didn't understood the question.

Comment: You can try to program in Python as you do in PHP (for example, using the obsolet mod_python) but it will become frustrating because Python syntax (specially its dependence of proper indentation) is not suited for such kind of code. I say it by my own experience :) Anyway, I prefer Python and would make a web application with Django or CherryPy (my favorite framework) but I think PHP is okay and if you want the "PHP way", you can have a good use of PHP. Even Java and its JSPs aren't as practical as PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The python cgi module](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html) might be what you want, though it is hard to tell exactly what you want.  You could also try using [WSGI](http://wsgi.org/wsgi/), which is low-level, similar in some ways to cgi.  Anyway, these interfaces leave you at a pretty low level, so if you're doing this just to learn "the hard way", this is an educational way of doing that.